# Jquery get data on XHR error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xmlhttprequest

If I make a jquery AJAX request which is succesful I get back my JSON data. However, If I make a request and I get somthing other than a 200 response code back, I cannot get back the data in the Jquery call back. I need the data as it has a description about the data.

```
success: function (data, tst, xhr) {
    $.log('XHR OK');
},
error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
    $.log('XHR ERROR ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
},
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What "data" are you talking about?  If there's a server error, where would any "data" come from (other than the error information in the xhr object)?

Comment: Yes, a JSON response like this {'error':'Your account was not found.'}

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the:

```
error: function (xhr, tst, err) {
    $.log('XHR ERROR ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
},
```

you can use

```
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    $.log('XHR ERROR ' + XMLHttpRequest.status);
    return JSON.parse(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
},
```

to get the JSON response in in event of an error.

```
XMLHttpRequest.responseText
```

Cheers.

Comment: Can you please update this answer to include the newer success/fail ajax style?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [jQuery JSONP plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-jsonp/). It adds an error callback to a JSON request like so:

```
$.jsonp({   
    url: "Your URL",
    data: {data: "Some Data"},
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(data, status) {
        // Do something with data here
    },
    error: function(xhr, text_status){
        // Handle the server error
    }
});
```

It does this using a timeout to wait for the server. Unfortunately, there is no other way of telling if the server response with something other than a 200 response.